# Command line way of stopping a process in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, autohotkey

Is there a command line way of stopping a process if I know the name of the exe (or better give a wildcard).  I was about to jump in and write an autohotkey script to do it but I thought I would look for out of the box ways first.

Interested in Windows XP and Vista.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/52159/kill-a-process-with-a-specific-command-line-from-command-line

Comment: Thanks @random.  I did have a look for similar but used "stop" rather than "kill" so didnt see that one. Ho hum!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

You can use the `taskkill` command.

**Note**: The command is not available in Windows XP Home/Starter Edition.

### Examples

```
taskkill /IM app.exe
taskkill /IM app*.exe
```

### Further reading

- [Taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell, you can use `Stop-Process` supplying either an id or name

Comment: Note however, that PowerShell is not supplied with the operating system for both XP and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wmic` (Which uses WMI):

```
wmic process where "NAME like '%PROCESS_NAME%'" call terminate
```